# Making toast errors not stack

Tags: angular, toast

Toast stacks errors:
[image]

My code is pretty much toast service for firing this on each error:

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastEvent } from '../../models/toast/toast-event';
import { ToastType } from '../../enums/toast-type';

@Injectable()
export class ToastService {

    public emitter: EventEmitter<ToastEvent> = new EventEmitter();

    public info(message: string, icon: string = 'fa-info-circle'): void {
        this.emitter.emit({ toast: { type: ToastType.Info, icon, message } });
    }

    public error(message: string, icon: string = 'fa-exclamation-triangle'): void {
        this.emitter.emit({ toast: { type: ToastType.Error, icon, message } });
    }
}
```

This service is then injected into components that reuse it for erros like this:

```
public async onSaveClick(): Promise<void> {
    // Check the form and show a toast if invalid
    if (!this.formIsValid()) {
        this.toastService.error('There are errors on the form');
        return;
    }

if (this.isEditingCurrentSkin) {
    await this.updateSkin().toPromise();
} else {
    await this.createSkin().toPromise();
}

this.loadAllSkins();
this.onGoBackClick();
```

}

Problem is when I have multiple errors they stack. How can I do this so it doesn't stack one on another?

Answer (score 0):

create a modal component for error and success messages . so once user click on ok close the modal in modal component. Play with input and output feature of components.